# Когда я пытаюсь подать программе на вход одну последовательность шестнадцатеричных чисел, отправляется другая, почему?

Tags: c, gdb

Вот код:

```
void return_input()
{
    char array[30];
    gets(array);
}

int main()
{
    return_input();

    return 0;
}
```

Запускаю программу в gdb. Программа запрашивает строку, отправляю:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

Значения вершины стека следующие:

```
(gdb) x/20x $esp
0xbffff340: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0xbffff350: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0xbffff360: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0xbffff370: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0xb7006141
0xbffff380: 0x00000000  0x5949442f  0x1bf9e23f  0x00000000
```

Подаю то же самое в виде шестнадцатеричных чисел:

```
\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41
```

Стек:

```
(gdb) x/20x $esp
0xbffff340: 0x785c3134  0x785c3134  0x785c3134  0x785c3134
0xbffff350: 0x785c3134  0x785c3134  0x785c3134  0x785c3134
0xbffff360: 0x785c3134  0x785c3134  0x785c3134  0x785c3134
0xbffff370: 0x785c3134  0x785c3134  0x785c3134  0x785c3134
0xbffff380: 0x785c3134  0x785c3134  0x785c3134  0x785c3134
```

В чем заключается проблема?

Comment: `\x` кто то должен интерпретировать. gets этого не делает и вы просто получаете строку символов как есть

Comment: Во-первых, функции `gets` в стандартной библиотеке больше нет. Во-вторых, функция `gets` читает из входа *строку*. Никаких "шестнадцатеричных чисел" она не знает и читать не умеет. Что вы подали на вход, то она и прочитала.

Comment: @Mike однако в Shellcoder's Handbook это работает, правда, через ввод команды: printf "\x41\x41\x41" | ./program

Comment: @SemyonKotov команда printf из утилит unix изображает такое же поведение, как вызов функции printf в C (правда в C это выполняет сам компилятор). т.е. она сама декодирует эту последовательность и выдает буквы 'A', в чем легко убедится, запустив ее без перенаправления программе, она выдаст 'AAA' на экран.

Comment: @Mike этим способом не выходит перезаписать адрес возврата тоже.

Comment: Что значит "не выходит", может вы подаете недостаточное количество букв A

Comment: @Mike я подаю их ровно столько, сколько необходимо подать (судя по результатам отладки в gdb), а если же я делал что-то не так, то даже не знаю, как мне следует определять нужное расстояние.

Comment: Найдите адрес в выводе gdb и в следующий раз пошлите сколько требуется букв

Comment: @avp однако, я так и делал. В ответ - обычная ошибка сегментирования

Comment: А вы чего ожидали?

Comment: @avp Я ожидал, что перезапишу адрес возврата и функция выполнится повторно

Comment: А какой у нее адрес? Неужели 0x41414141

Comment: @avp Нет, я подавал вот это: \xef\x11\x40\x00

Comment: Т.е. вы стоите в gdb *после* gets, видите, что заменили адрес возврата на адрес return_input, отпускаете программу и вместо входа в return_input получаете segfault? Попробуйте пройти по инструкциям (команда si в gdb)

Comment: @avp ставил в gdb точки останова, смотрел состояние стека до gets() и после (когда вводил строку, переполняющую буфер). 4 последних символа - DDDD, чтобы было видно, какая часть затирается именно этими символами. После подбора нужной длины пытался эти DDDD заменить адресом и передать программе различными способами, и ни один не сработал.

Comment: ОС-то какая (и система вообще 32 или 64)? Также асм код надо вам посмотреть, чтобы точно понимать где идете по командам в gdb и идти по si. Наверное увидите, что не выходит

Comment: @avp 32 бита, Linux

Comment: @avp asm код смотрел, конечно же, именно оттуда и брал адреса. Попробую идти по si, наблюдая за значением стека и регистров, может, и получится.

Comment: @SemyonKotov, к сожалению, у меня в Ubuntu 64-bit gcc 7.3.0 при выходе сама функция  вообще просто определяет `*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated` (код кладет "sentinel" сразу после буфера, который и проверяет перед выходом).

Comment: Впрочем, компиляция с `-fno-stack-check -fno-stack-protector` разрешила проблему check stack, а           `set {int}0x7fffffffddb8 = 0x555546ca`  в gdb (мне было лень подбирать символы в utf-8 для ввода 0x46ca)  успешно второй раз вызвала функцию ввода. Попробуйте подменить адрес возврата командой gdb, что получится? (у меня нет 32-bit Linux)